# JAXB-Unmarshalling CDATA is not ignoring Whitespaces and newlines

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to develop a java file that can read XML elements as Java Objects.I am using **JAXB unmarshalling** to read XML. XML file has a nested structure.

```
 <TAG1>
     <TAG2>
         <TAG3>
            <TAG><![CDATA[helloooo
                       buddiessss...]]>
             </TAG>
         </TAG3>
     </TAG2>
 </TAG1>
```

Likewise, There are many tags inside . While unmarshalling, It prints the newline and spaces in CDATA.

I want to print the whole CDATA section as a single string like **helloooo buddies**.

No spaces and newlines are needed. Someone help me out.

Comment: Spaces and newlines are part of the data and it is expected behaviour that these are retained during unmarshalling. If you want to get rid of them you will have to do so programmatically after unmarshalling.

Comment: what If the <![CDATA[  ...... ]] is also in new line? In that case, MY output is like **"\n      <![CDATA[.......]]>"**. I dont want that escape sequences.@MarkusBenko

Answer (score 0):

i found the Answer. Use

> @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)

to avoid unwanted newlines and spaces.